# How to get add/list/... link of a view in flask app builder?

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

I am using flask app builder. Currently I am using the following code to access the view.

```
appbuilder.add_view(ItemView, "Item")
```

By default, it redirects me to listing page. And I know I can change the behaviour by overriding default_view.

But I am looking something as the following.

```
appbuilder.add_link("Add New Item", ItemView().get_add_link())

appbuilder.add_link("List Items", ItemView().get_list_link())
```

How to get the view URL of the list/add pages of the view?

Comment: are you using vanilla flask or are you using flask-appbuilder?

Comment: @Oz123, I forgot to mention it. I am using flask app builder.

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with it, but I added a tag, it might help lure users and focus your potential helpers. Also, it might help if you reveal a bit of more code of your application, so people might know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it at that point since you don't have app context, with context you could use Flask url_for('ItemView.add').

On this case just use relative URL path:

appbuilder.add_link("Add New Item", href='/itemview/add')